# Problem 2-26 (a) of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the piecewise-defined function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is $e^{\frac{-2(x^2+1)}{(x^2-1)^2}}$ on $(-1, 1)$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Problem 2-26 (a) of Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* asks to show that that $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}$. But for $f'$ to be continuous, the right-hand derivative of $f$ at -1 and left-hand derivative of $f$ at 1 must be 0, since $f'$ is $0$ everywhere outside$ (-1, 1)$.

So since $f'(x)=e^{\frac{-2(x^2+1)}{(x^2-1)^2}}\frac{4x^3+12x}{(x^2-1)^3}$ on $(-1, 1)$, I was wondering how to prove that $lim_{x\rightarrow{1}}e^{\frac{-2(x^2+1)}{(x^2-1)^2}}\frac{4x^3+12x}{(x^2-1)^3}=0=lim_{x\rightarrow{-1}}e^{\frac{-2(x^2+1)}{(x^2-1)^2}}\frac{4x^3+12x}{(x^2-1)^3}$. But now, come to think of it, to show $f$ is $C^\infty$, we have to show that $lim_{x\rightarrow\pm{1}}f^{(i)}(x)=0$ $\forall{i}\in\mathbb{N}$. Does anyone know how to do this or know a better way of approaching the problem?

Comment: Show by induction that $f^{(i)} = \frac{P_i(x)}{(x^2-1)^{n_i}}e^\cdots$, then show that the limit of this expression is $0$ when $x\rightarrow \pm 1$.

Comment: Ok, you're saying we don't have to show what $P_i(x)$ actually is for all $i$, that we can just show it's some polynomial by induction, right? Then the limit will have to how to 0 because the exponential grows faster, right?

Comment: There's no use trying to find a closed formula for $P_i(x)$, right?

Comment: Exactly, the proof only needs that $P_i$ is a polynomial. You don't need to prove more.

Answer (score 1):

*From the comments above.*

---

Show by induction that $f^{(i)} = \frac{P_i(x)}{(x^2−1)^{n_i}} e^{\dots}$, then show that the limit of this expression is $0$ when $x \to \pm 1$.
The proof only needs that $P_i$ is a polynomial.